# Import html template file into svelte

Tags: html, node.js, svelte

I have a .html which needs data inserted from svelte using ${} syntax. I haven't found any way to include that html without resorting to inserting as a string into the svelte component.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much Svelte can do here, for Svelte to do it's thing it requires a compile step.

If it's possible to rename the .html file to a .svelve file and compile it like the other components, that would be preferable.
But when the html comes from an api that's not possible.

An option is to use [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com) or another template engine to insert data from Svelte into the html. (but that resorts to inserting it as a string, see [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c89c465901af4843a0b145be5a30d2e9?version=3.46.4))

A last option I can think of is to place a `<div bind:this={el} />` and use DOM api's to create and manage the html (not recommended)

Comment: Yes, I also got a project like this were the html was imported, passing trough Liquid (or Handlebars) and then render it with {@html ...}